# ActionScript3 DataGrid how to display content on browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datagrid

Thanks very much for being the most answered community on the web.

I have this small problem:

I want to read a database using Tomcat Servlets into a ActionScript DataGrid. 
Please mind that I want it to be pure ActionScript; no mix with MXML. 
I have already done a exercise with MXML and DataGrid but it is not meeting my requirement. 
I want to understand how to use ActionScript libraries.

thanks for listening

Here is the code:

```
package {
  import flash.display.*;
  import spark.components.DataGrid;
  import mx.collections.ArrayList;

  public class EmpDBDebug extends Sprite {
      public var empDG:DataGrid;
      public var DGArray:Array = [
                {Album:'Slanted and Enchanted'},
                {Album:'Brighten the Corners'}];
      public var DGArrayList:ArrayList;         

    public function EmpDBDebug() {
      empDG = new DataGrid();
      DGArrayList = new ArrayList(DGArray);

      empDG.dataProvider = DGArrayList;
      addChild(empDG);
    }   
  }
}
```

This is a simplified version of what I want to do. I have replace Servlet with Array. All I want to do is display the DataGrid content on browser. I am not able to do that. It is refreshing but everything is blank. Hope I am doing something wrong. I tried everything. I replace Sprite with Stage but still nothing works.

Since I want to do it in pure ActionScript without using MXML, are there any other libraries which I should be using. And again I am mostly using Notepad++ and MonsterDebugger. I do not have access to fl.data.DataProvider libraries. Let us rule it for the time being. I am bit confused with Flash Licensing. Can I do it with Apache Flex?

Can you throw some light.

thanks again

RR23850

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It already has an example of how to create a data grid and use it : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa8.html

Comment: This example uses fl.data.DataProvider which is not accessible to me. I am trying to compile outside FlashBuilder. I am using mxmlc. So, my options are limited to use mx.* components. Most mx.* example are showing only mxml tags code which I want to avoid.

Comment: Hi,

I figured out what I was doing wrong. You cannot mix mx.* with flash.* controls. 
Something like flash.display. Sprite will not write a mx.* component. 
mx.* components must be written with mxml. There is no other go.
To prove my point I did a small PoC where I tried to write mx.controls.Text class
to Sprite. It did not work either, although there were no compiler warnings.

Please correct me if reality is otherwise.

thanks very much

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. Glad you were able to sort it out. Happy coding :)